# How to convert string to dig readable format rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I using ruby on rails.
I have a string that needs to converted to dig readable format

```
"search.user[0].user_id" convert this to [:search, :user,0, :user_id]
```

i am trying to use

```
"search.user[0].user_id".split('.').map(&:to_sym) which result to [:search, :user[0], :user_id]
```

How can i further split array index, string can position array user[0] at any position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse your expression you can use:

```rb
"search.user[0].user_id".split(/]?\.|\[/).map{|k| k =~ /\A\d+\z/ && k.to_i || k.to_sym }
# => [:search, :user, 0, :user_id]
```

For a more generic approach also look at [jsonpath](https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath) (that parses more complex paths like `$.store.book[*](category,author)`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do that.

```
str = "search.user[0].user_id"
```

**Use [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split)**

```
r1 = /\[|\]\.|\./
r2 = /\A\d+\z/
```

```
str.split(r1).map do |s|
  if s.match? r2
    s.to_i
  else
    s.to_sym
  end
end
  #=> [:search, :user, 0, :user_id]
```

We can write the regular expressions in *free-spacing* mode to make them self-documenting.

```
r1 = /
     \[    # match '['
     |     # or
     \]\.  # match '].'
     |     # or
     \.    # match '.'
     /x    # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
r2 = /
     \A    # match beginning of string
     \d+   # match one or more digits
     \z    # match end of string
     /x    # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

**Use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan)**

```
r1 = /
     [^\[\]\.] # match any character other than '[', ']' and '.'
     +         # perform above match one or more times
     /x        # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`r2` is as above.

```
str.scan(r1).map do |s|
  if s.match? r2
    s.to_i
  else
    s.to_sym
  end
end
  #=> [:search, :user, 0, :user_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can converted string like below

```
str = "search.user[0].user_id" 
str.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/)
    .map { |s| s.empty? ? nil : (s.match?(/[0-9]+/)) ? s.to_i : s.to_sym }
    .compact
```

it will return

```
[:search, :user, 0, :user_id]
```

Comment: You can simplify by changing the regex slightly: `str.split(/\W+/).map { |s| s.match?(/\d/) ? s.to_i : s.to_sym }`. Note that `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\W` (and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\w`). I don't know why you don't want to match `_`, however.